# What caused the different way of cast consecutive column in pandas dataframe from float64 to int32 between Pandas = 2.1.4 and Pandas = 1.4.2

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two env, one Pandas = 2.1.4, another Pandas = 1.4.2, when I run the following code they give different result.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col0': ['a', 'b'], 'col1': [1.0, 2.0], 'col2': [3.0, 4.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
df.iloc[:,1:3] = df.iloc[:,1:3].astype('int32')
print(df)
```

1.4.2 gives:

```
  col0  col1  col2
0    a   1.0   3.0
1    b   2.0   4.0
  col0  col1  col2
0    a     1     3
1    b     2     4
```

2.1.4 gives:

```
  col0  col1  col2
0    a   1.0   3.0
1    b   2.0   4.0
  col0  col1  col2
0    a   1.0   3.0
1    b   2.0   4.0
```

How do I modify the code so it will give the same result as in the 1.4.2 output for both 1.4.2 and 2.1.4? Please keep it one liner.

Also what changes between two Pandas version caused the different behaviour?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that assigning to **part of a column** doesn't  downcast the dtype. If you have a float, assigning an int will keep the float.

You should probably use [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
df = df.astype(dict.fromkeys(df.columns[1:3], 'int32'))
```

Or, if there can be a risk of error:

```
df = df.astype(dict.fromkeys(df.columns[1:3], 'int32'), errors='ignore')
```

Note that there is no problem if you assign the **full column without slicing**:

```
cols = df.columns[1:3]

df[cols] = df[cols].astype('int32')
```